# How can I use MCLR on a pic18f4550 using Proteus?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, mplab

I'm trying to use Master clear(MCLR) on a pic18f4550 with Proteus, but whenever I press the button to do so, the red and blue dots that represent on and off in Proteus turn yellow and the LED doesn't turn off.

I'm trying to replicate a Proteus file that my professor used and it worked perfectly, but even though it seems my file is looking exactly the same as his, it doesn't work.

Here's my circuit:
[image: my circuit],

M professor's circuit:
[image: professor's circuit],

and here's what happens when I press the MCLR button:
[image: MCLR button].

Here's the code, but I'm pretty sure that's not the problem

```
#include <p18f4550.h>
#include <delays.h>
#pragma config  FOSC    =   HS
#pragma config  PWRT    =   ON
#pragma config  PBADEN  =   OFF
#pragma config  WDT     =   OFF
#pragma config  LVP     =   OFF
#pragma config  MCLRE   =   ON
void main()             
{
    TRISB=0x00;         
    PORTB=0b11111111;    
                                         
    while (1){
        PORTBbits.RB1 = 0;
        Delay1KTCYx(100);
        PORTBbits.RB1 = 1;
        Delay1KTCYx (100);
    }                             
}
```

The only error message I get is from Proteus, that says:

> [PIC18]PC=0x00BC $MCLR$ is low. Processor is in reset.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and if you want help, post all relevant information.  Links to offset information are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Check voltage level on pin 1 (MCLR )!

Answer (score 1):

Connect MCLR pin with 10K resistor to power.